# Issue w/PHP syntax

Tags: php, ajax

I need a simple php function to mimic an Ajax form submission - basically in the form there is a radio button "ajax" and it is either set to yes or no. I just need to mimic successful/failing ajax calls...

HTML

```
<label for="">Ajax Success*<input type="radio" name="ajax" id="yes" value="yes" checked>Yes<input type="radio" name="ajax" id="no" value="no">No</label>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $ajax = $_POST["ajax"];
    if(isset($_POST['ajax'] == "yes"))  {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "failure";
    }
?>
```

if I remove the isset, I get an 'undefined index' error, if I put it in I get a syntax error but it looks correct to me...

I just need to send back an echo depending on what option is selected for the input 'ajax'

thx

Comment: Also, make sure that you are wrapping your form controls in `<form method="post" action="YOURURL"></form>`. If you aren't actually posting any data, PHP will return that you have an undefined index.

Comment: @ChrisB of course, I just put a snippet up for sake of brevity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isset($_POST['ajax'] == "yes")` doesn't make sense. You want to check if it's set, and *then* check if its  value is equal to `"yes`":

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == "yes") {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: The value of the radio box must be "yes"

Comment: rekire - not intentional, I gave you an upvote and selected the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

As your code does, I'll say you use your defined variable like in this example:

```
<?php
    $ajax = $_POST["ajax"];
    if($ajax == "yes")  {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "failure";
    }
?>
```

Because if the variable has the value "yes" it'll be ok and undefined or other value will end in "failure".